# Is the coupling of space and time static or dynamic?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime

I'll venture to guess that the answer is *dynamic* but then that means that there must be some sort of compliant *structure* or rather structure with *memory* that couples the two quantities.

But then the concept of memory presumes time, so that presents a problem, right?

What would that structure be? In GR would that be the *metric tensor*? My elementary understanding is that tensor is static.

Einstein's special theory of relativity seems to address only a static relation between space and time, a steady state solution from one state to another, and I admit I just don't understand the mathematics to say that GR provides a *dynamic* coupling.

Or is this question just off-base, that space and time don't exist as separate entities but rather as one: spacetime?

Comment: What do you mean by the phrase "coupling of space and time"? Usually, a *coupling* in field theory is a term in a Lagrangian that is an expression in two fields that doesn't separate into the sum of expressions in the individual fields, but there are no fields for "space" and "time" - the closest would be the metric tensor as a "field for spacetime".

Comment: I don't think this means anything. There is no *coupling* between space and time. Spacetime is a 4D manifold, and the split between 3 space and 1 time dimensions is observer dependent.

Comment: Didn't Einstein resolve the point of spacetime being one thing 100+ years ago?

Comment: There is such a thing as the $3+1$ decomposition of the Einstein equations, but this has to do with the formulation of the Cauchy problem for the Einstein equations; there is no sense in which you have some time and spatial field coupling to each other. The Einstein-Hilbert action is for a single field $g_{ab}$, the metric, which contains non-linear self-interactions, but these are not in any sense couplings between space and time.

Comment: @ACuriousMind  *coupling* in a sense how one variable in a *system* or *model* of a system connects to other variables. The coupling could be null, loosely coupled or tightly coupled. It could be static (algebraic) or dynamic for example how differential or integral equations couple variables - in that it depends on history or memory.

Comment: @JamalS you may have answered my question. If the metric is puely algebraic albeit nonlinear and it internally couples space and time, then the coupling is in a sense static.

Comment: @JamalS is the metric time invariant?

Comment: @docscience The theory of general relativity is invariant under diffeomorphisms, or coordinate transformations. That is to say, if I have a spacetime described by coordinates $x^\mu$, and another in $x'^\mu$, then although the metrics $g_{ab}$ and $g'_{ab}$ may have a different form, they still describe the *same* manifold or physics. So, taking for example $t \to f(t)$ will not change the physics.

Answer (score 2):

We have a very clear understanding of what *coupling* means in physics, but I think you may be using it in the question, in the control theory sense, or another. From what I understand, in control theory, there is a notion of coupling if the variation in time of a state is dependent on other states, or if the transfer matrix mixes inputs and outputs.

I would argue we cannot apply this viewpoint to general relativity at all, but if we did, it would not be coupled in that sense. Among *many* other details, the Cauchy problem in general relativity consists of specifying initial conditions for the metric, $g_{ab}(t_0)$ and $\partial_t g_{ab}(t_0)$, which specify a hypersurface with some induced metric and second fundamental form.

The field equations do not care how the system got to that state, and will possess the same solution for those initial conditions.

---

Now to clarify on what we mean by coupling in physics. General relativity can be described, in the absence of other matter and any variations of classical GR, with the action,

$$S = \frac{1}{2\kappa_N}\int d^Nx \, \sqrt{|g|} \, R.$$

The Ricci scalar describing intrinsic curvature, $R$, contains many terms with factors of the metric, and its derivatives, and so we say that the field $g_{ab}$ has self-interactions. So, diagramatically, in linearised general relativity, we can have an interaction involving three $g$ like so: [image]

This is due to the fact general relativity is a non-linear theory, and the field essentially interacts with itself, but this is not to be confused with thinking that states of the system evolve in a way dependent upon their history.

Comment: "...the field essentially interacts with itself ..." causes me to think that the field is a system within itself. And since there is no evolution of states dependent on history (time) then the relation is purely algebraic, so then static? Or are you just saying there are no states, period, and that the metric is more of a fixed parameter?

Comment: @docscience I don't know what you mean by static and dynamic coupling - we don't really have that notion in physics. (Well, in string theory you can have a coupling that depends on a field which evolves - that's the closest thing I can think of.) As for the metric, when you solve the Einstein field equations, you get a $g_{ab}$ out of it. It can depend on time, in which case distances change with time along the manifold, but in the end you have a fixed, closed-form $g_{ab}$ which is known.

Comment: @docscience It's clear you must be thinking with control theory terminology, so to help answer your question, using the simplest system you can think of in control theory, describe to me the difference between dynamic and static coupling in your field. Then I'll tell you whether that makes sense in some way in physics.

Comment: Static example: Ohm's law: $I=\frac{V}{R}$; a static, algebraic relationship coupling applied potential across the resistor to current through it; no memory.  Dynamic example: Exponential response of a series RC circuit: $RC\frac{di}{dt}=-i+C\frac{dV}{dt}$, a dynamic coupling between applied potential and current through the circuit. Thanks

Comment: @docscience When you speak of "memory" in GR, Jamal's pithy text, "*the Cauchy problem in general relativity consists of specifying initial conditions for the metric, $g_{ab}(t_0)$ and $\partial_t g_{ab}(t_0)$, which specify a hypersurface with some induced metric and second fundamental form.

The field equations do not care how the system got to that state, and will possess the same solution for those initial conditions.*" tells you precisely what form that "memory" takes, namely the metric and its dervatives on the hypersurface.

Comment: @docscience This, from my fading memory of control theory, is precisely what a control theorist would call the system state. It is an infinite dimensional state, and GTR has the added complication that one cannot in general define a global foliation that allows the introduction of a global time co-ordinate (as one can in special solutions like FLRW metric), but locally (i.e. in nonzero width neighborhoods that are small enough) the notions are still very much like one encounters in control theory. It also seems that, from your definition, GTR is "dynamically coupled", but I don't think that ..

Comment: @docscience ... nomenclature adds very much to the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Since it was not clear totally what was meant by coupled, and maybe dynamic, this simply explains in what sense it can be dynamic or not, and at the end something on coupling.

With @docscience's definition of dynamic then special relativity, i.e. spacetime without gravity has a static metric. It does not change (physically it does not depend on time or position in space), although the components can be different in different coordinate frames, and you can define a rotating coordinate system where there are cross space-time terms. Still, you can find a global coordinate system where all the metric terms are constant, I.e., the Lorentz metric.

For gravity, i.e., General Relativity, it is generally dynamic, it changes with coordinate position and time, in general. Though one can get somewhat formal and say that it is determined (fixed?) by the solution for all spacetime, it certainly can be dynamic in the sense that it can depend on time and space (there are ways of making these statement in an invariant way by referring to space like or timelike symmetries, or coordinate systems with certain properties, I am being a little hand wavy here). And in general (I.e., except in Lorentz spacetime) one can not find a global (or nearly global except for maybe some singularity) coordinate system where they are constant. Of course, there can be static and stationary solutions as well, with a spatial dependence and no time dependence).

The dynamics of General Relativity can be time dependent sources creating time dependent metrics (or more correctly without a timelike symmetry or Killing vector), inside or outside, or vacuum solutions with no timelike symmetry such as for gravitational waves. Since gravity affects all matter or energy, it'll change their trajectory which then, can affect the metric - all the nonlinearities of GR.

The metric, in GR, is totally NOT a fixed parameter, it is the entity for which the EFE provides relationships on how it can vary.

As for coupling, there can be mixed time-spatial terms like in any rotating solution - not what is usually called coupling in physics, but it can have cross terms. A uniformly rotating axially symmetric body, for the outside solution, the Kerr solution, does have cross terms. But, you would need to be more specific as to what you mean by coupled - if you mean that the timelike and space like evolution of the metric are related, yes, there are equations that relate them, in a very complicated nonlinear way. If you mean anything else, you'd need to define it.